# What's the difference between passing a value and passing a callback in a React setState hook function?

Tags: javascript, reactjs, react-hooks, use-state

Let say I declare a local state using React hook `useState()` :

```
const [count, setCount] = useState(0);
```

Later I would like to update the state and trigger the re-rendering:

1. Set the state by passing the value

```
<button onClick={() => setCount(count+1)}
```

2. Set the state by passing a callback

```
<button onClick={() => setCount((prev_count) => prev_count+1)}
```

What is the difference between these 2 types of update?

Comment: Does this answer your question? [lifecycle event state and prevState in react.js](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/39806802/lifecycle-event-state-and-prevstate-in-react-js)

Comment: Does this answer your question? https://stackoverflow.com/a/70509910/9765167

Comment: This might help https://blog.logrocket.com/react-hooks-cheat-sheet-unlock-solutions-to-common-problems-af4caf699e70/#usestate

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Here it does not make any difference but once your application grows bigger and you have `count` used at many places, there is a possibility that multiple `setState` calls would be happening and queuing up data to be rendered to the DOM, and hence the actual value of count might not be what you think.

This is exactly why it is recommended to use the previous state in the callback. `prevState` is always a reliable solution without tracing every state update to know what the `count` is.

Answer (score 2):

1. Passing a callback will provide you the access to current state via callback function argument `setCount((curr_count) => curr_count+1)` .
2. If your state updates are batched , using the state value in `setCount(count+1)` will provide you the stale state, chances are there that you might access the previous state.